# Как убрать синюю обводку у формы поиска

Tags: search

В заголовке главный вопрос.
Сделал я форму поиска, но при нажатии на нее появляется синяя обводка. И вот, главный вопрос: **Как ее убрать?**

Форма на сайте - [bifot.ru/cloud/search/index.html](http://bifot.ru/cloud/search/index.html)

**Скрин, чтобы понять лучше** - http://bifot.ru/cloud/search.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
input:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
outline: none;
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Не использовать неизвестные вам css-фреймворки.
2. Не копировать бездумно код из форумов
3. Убрать свойства box-shadow у строки поиска в состоянии active.

**Обновление**

```
.form-search input:focus {
  outline: 0;
}
```

Comment: 1. Это фреймворки всем известны.
2. См. 1.
3. Не помогло.